# The length of geodesic

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

[image]

I wonder, in the remark, how to see the length of the geodesic is less than $\epsilon$?

Comment: Follow from the item (i).

Comment: @MoisheCohen can you be more precise, I know he said it's from (i), but I just can't see.

Answer (score 2):

The exponential map is an isometry in the radial direction. Therefore the length of the geodesic $c_v$ is $|v|$.

Answer (score 0):

Recall $X.g(Y, Z) = g(D_X Y, Z) + g(Y, D_X Z)$, thus $\frac{dg(c_v'(t),c_v'(t))}{dt}=2(D_{c_v'(t)}{c_v'(t)},c_v'(t))=0$, therefore $|c_v'(t)|$ is constant. So $L(c_v(t))=\int_{0}^{1}|c_v'(t)|dt=\int_{0}^{1}|v|dt=|v|<\epsilon$.